# Mule CE 3.6.1 HTTP Request url encoding issue

Tags: http, encoding, mule

I have a Mule flow which uses HTTP Request endpoint in Mule CE3.6.1. It needs to use encoded HTTP url to get the correct data.

Please note the encoded url: /items?q=%2Blabel%3ABOTV2309H*%20%2Bparent.uri%3A%5C%2Fbristol%5C%2Ftest%5C%2Fgateway%5C%2F*&rows=100&start=0

Here is the test flow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.6.1"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8089" basePath="/" usePersistentConnections="false" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Config_Search" host="testserver" port="80" basePath="/index" usePersistentConnections="false" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
<flow name="testFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="*" allowedMethods="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>


    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Config_Search" path="/items?q=%2Blabel%3ABOTV2309H*%20%2Bparent.uri%3A%5C%2Fbristol%5C%2Ftest%5C%2Fgateway%5C%2F*&amp;rows=100&amp;start=0" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
</mule>
```

When the Mule flow runs, here is the url being requested (Found through wireshark):

```
/items?q=%20label%3ABOTV2309H%2A%20%20parent.uri%3A%5C%2Fbristol%5C%2Ftest%5C%2Fgateway%5C%2F%2A&rows=100&start=0
```

Please note %2B is replaced with %20 in two places, which obviously do not return the data I need.

Is this an issue with HTTP endpoint?

Thanks!

Comment: Found someone else has posted a similar question. http://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/30380/plus-sign-in-http-url.html

Answer (score 0):

I divided the params into query and uri params. Then this issue got resolved.

```
<http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Config_Search" path="/items" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:query-param paramName="q" value="+label:BOTV2309H* +parent.uri:\/test\/gateway\/*"/>
            <http:uri-param paramName="rows" value="100"/>
            <http:uri-param paramName="start" value="0"/>
        </http:request-builder>
    </http:request>
```